# HierarchyID in .NET Dataview

Tags: .net, sql-server, hierarchyid

Code previously worked, but installing on new PC where it does not.  Probably missing a setting?  Using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

SQL Server 2012 has db table with hierarchyID field, but it has NULL values.  This table is queried into a dataview.  The item for this field is not recognized as a hierarchyID datatype.  The code continues to work with geography datatypes.

Comment: Sir a piece of Code not working is a very vague term, could you please share more information like , an error message or maybe an example of what you expect it to do and it is not doing. Thank you.

Comment: Error message is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store </1/> in HID Column.  Expected type is SqlHierarchyId.

Comment: The code is simple:  
             Dim H As SqlHierarchyId = SqlHierarchyId.Parse("/1/")
            dvFamilyMemberCollection(0).Item("hid") = H
            
            Where the dataview was created from a query of the database table with a field HID that was of datatype hierarchyID

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the use of HierarchyID as a datatype because: a) a database query of a hierarchyID column did not create a similar datatype in the dataview and b) there is difficulty handling NULL values for hierarchyID.

Instead, I implemented ORDPATH as described by P O'Neil, E O'Neil, S Pal et al. 2004: http://www.cs.umb.edu/~poneil/ordpath.pdf.  It uses a DB table LiOi with values from the table in the article which is rendered into dvORDPATH.  I had written this code years before.  With this code you create an ORDPATH datatype using the Dewey notation (e.g. /1/1/15/7/).  This datatype has three properties, 1) the ORDPATH per se which is a concatenated bitstring (in this case 0100101001100011101111); 2) it's Dewey; and 3) the level in the hierarchy.

This methodology is similar to hierarchyID.  The principle difference is that hierarchyID uses a hex and my code a base-2 concatenated bitstring.  Both sort by the tree hierarchy.

```
Public Class ORDPATH
'user defined datatype
'based on P O'Neil, E O'Neil, S Pal et al. 2004
'http://www.cs.umb.edu/~poneil/ordpath.pdf 
'
'Code by David A Stumpf, MD, PhD; Evanston, IL
'Dec 2009

Public Shared DeweyRef As String
Public Dewey As String   'human readable hierarchy
Public HID As String     'hierarchyID
Public Level As Integer  'level in hierarchy
Public Shared dvORDPATH As DataView
Public Shared Multiplier As Long = 1

Public Shared Sub InitializeORDPATH()
    dvORDPATH = DataLib.QryToData("Select * from dbo.LiOi", EnumLib.DBList.Gen, EnumLib.DataObj.DataView)
    dvORDPATH.Sort = "Oi_MIN"
End Sub

Public Shared Function CreateUsingDewey(ByVal DeweyStr As String, Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = "/", Optional ByVal BeginEndDelimiter As Boolean = True) As ORDPATH
    'creates new ORDPATH object using submitted Dewey
    DeweyRef = IIf(Delimiter <> "/", Replace(DeweyStr, Delimiter, "/"), DeweyStr)
    Dim O As ORDPATH = CreateORDPATH(Delimiter, BeginEndDelimiter)
    CreateUsingDewey = O
End Function

Public Shared Property CreateORDPATH(Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = "/", Optional ByVal BeginEndDelimiter As Boolean = True) As ORDPATH
    'instantiates ORDPATH object and its properties: HID, Dewey, and Level
    Get
        'SetUpDV()
        Dim O As ORDPATH = New ORDPATH
        O.Dewey = IIf(BeginEndDelimiter, "", "/") & IIf(Delimiter <> "/", Replace(DeweyRef, Delimiter, "/"), DeweyRef) & IIf(BeginEndDelimiter, "", "/")
        Dim DeweySplit() = O.Dewey.Split("/")
        Dim OP As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 1 To DeweySplit.Length - 2
            OP = OP & GetLiOifromDV(Val(DeweySplit(i))) '& GenLib.OrdpathDelimiter
        Next
        O.HID = OP
        O.Level = DeweySplit.Length - 2
        Return O
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ORDPATH)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared Function GetLiOifromDV(ByVal DeweyItem As Double) As String
    Dim DI As Double = DeweyItem * Multiplier
    Dim Rtn As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To dvORDPATH.Count - 1
        With dvORDPATH(i)
            If DI >= .Item("oi_min") And DI <= .Item("oi_max") Then
                Dim X As String = Trim(NumberToBase2(DI - .Item("oi_min")))
                'Dim X As String = Trim(NumberToHex(DI - .Item("oi_min")))
                Rtn = Trim(.Item("BITSTRING_ROOT")) & GenLib.LPad(X, .Item("li"), "0")
            End If
        End With
    Next
    GetLiOifromDV = Rtn
End Function

Public Shared Function NumberToHex(ByVal N As Object) As String
    'not used
    NumberToHex = Hex(N)
End Function

Public Shared Function StrToByte(ByVal S As String) As Byte()
    'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/fxref_mscorlib/html/c590603b-8901-253c-78bf-171950a57438.htm
    StrToByte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(S)
End Function

Public Shared Function NumberToBase2(ByVal N As Double) As String
    'http://www.helpwithpcs.com/courses/binary-numbers.htm
    'simple logic: iterative division by two, retaining remainder as digit in converted number
    'this might be useful in future: 
    '  http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/05/converting-hexadecimal-or-binary-to.html
    'fractions not yet done, but see: http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/Num/frac.htm
    Dim B2 As String = ""
    Dim V As Long = Int(N)
    Dim VN As Long = V
    Dim X As Long  'remainder
    Do While VN > 0
        VN = Math.DivRem(VN, 2, X)  'integer of result of division
        B2 = Trim(Str(X)) & B2
    Loop
    NumberToBase2 = B2
End Function

Public Overloads Shared Function ToString(ByVal HID As String) As String
    'Li and Oi are components
    'no Li is repeated in any other HID component.  
    'Thus you can run thru the Li options until found
    '  This tells you the length of the Oi component
    'SetUpDV()
    Dim OP As String = Trim(Replace(HID.ToString, Stegenography.OrdpathDelimiter, ""))
    Dim D As Integer = 1
    Dim S As String = "/"

    For i As Integer = 0 To 100
        For j As Integer = 0 To dvORDPATH.Count - 1
            Dim L As Integer = Len(Trim(dvORDPATH(j).Item("bitstring_root")))
            If Mid(OP, D, L) = Trim(dvORDPATH(j).Item("bitstring_root")) Then
                S = S & Trim(Str((IM.Base2ToNumber(Mid(OP, D + L, dvORDPATH(j).Item("li"))) + dvORDPATH(j).Item("Oi_Min")) / Multiplier)) & "/"
                D = D + L + dvORDPATH(j).Item("li")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If D >= Len(OP) Then Exit For
    Next
    ToString = S
End Function

Public Shared Function GetParent(ByVal HID_Dewey As String) As String
    Dim P As String = HID_Dewey.ToString
    If InStr(P, "/") > 0 Then
        GetParent = Mid(Trim(P), 1, InStrRev(Trim(P), "/", Len(Trim(P)) - 1))
        If GetParent = "/" Then GetParent = Nothing
    Else
        GetParent = Nothing
    End If
End Function

Public Shared Function GetAncestors(ByVal HID_Dewey As String, ByVal GenerationsBack As Integer) As String
    Dim A As String = HID_Dewey.ToString
    For i As Integer = 1 To GenerationsBack
        If A Is Nothing Then Exit For
        A = GetParent(A)
    Next
    GetAncestors = A
End Function

Public Shared Function GetRoot(ByVal HID_Dewey As String) As String
    GetRoot = Mid(HID_Dewey, 1, InStr(Mid(HID_Dewey, 2), "/") + 1)
End Function

Public Shared Sub ORDPATHTest()
    Dim HIDStr As String = "/1/5/3/1/11/;/100/10000/;/1/5/2/1/5/6/7/;/100/10001/;/1/5/3/-9/11/;/1/5/3/2/3/;/1/5/4/;/1/5/3/2/4/;/1/5/3/2/3/6/;/1/5/3/;/1/5/3/2/;/1/5/;/1/;/2/;/2/1/;/2/0.5/;/2/0.4/;/2/0.43/"
    Dim T1 As Long = My.Computer.Clock.TickCount
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim T As DataTable = ds.Tables.Add
    Dim C1 As DataColumn = T.Columns.Add("HID")
    Dim C2 As DataColumn = T.Columns.Add("Dewey")
    Dim C0 As DataColumn = T.Columns.Add("i")
    Dim C3 As DataColumn = T.Columns.Add("Lvl")
    Dim dv As DataView = ds.DefaultViewManager.CreateDataView(ds.Tables(0))

    Dim H() As String = HIDStr.Split(";")
    DataLib.QryToData("delete from dbo.ORDPATH_Tests", EnumLib.DBList.Gen, EnumLib.DataObj.DataSet)

    For i = 0 To H.Length - 1
        Dim O1 As ORDPATH = ORDPATH.CreateUsingDewey(H(i))
        'Dim HSql As Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId
        Dim rw1 As DataRow = dv.Table.Rows.Add
        rw1.Item("i") = i
        rw1.Item("HID") = O1.HID
        rw1.Item("Dewey") = O1.Dewey
        rw1.Item("Lvl") = O1.Level
        ' Dim B As Byte() = StrToByte(O1.HID)
        Dim CB As Byte() = Compression.Compress(StrToByte(O1.HID))
        'Dim SR As System.IO.Stream
        'SR.Read(B, 0, B.Length)
        ' Dim gz As System.IO.Compression.GZipStream = New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(SR, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress)

        'Dim B As Byte() = New Byte[(O1.HID) / 2]
        DataLib.QryToData("insert into ordpath_tests (i,dewey,ordpath,ORDPATH_BIT,hid ) values(" & i & ",'" & O1.Dewey & "','" & O1.HID & "'," & System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(StrToByte(O1.HID)) & ",'" & O1.Dewey & "' )", EnumLib.DBList.Gen, EnumLib.DataObj.DataSet)
        'DataLib.QryToData("insert into ordpath_tests (i,dewey,ordpath,hid ) values(" & i & ",'" & O1.Dewey & "','" & O1.HID & "','" & O1.Dewey & "' )", EnumLib.DBList.Gen, EnumLib.DataObj.DataSet)
        '"0x" & O1.HID 
    Next
    Dim S As String = ""
    For i = 0 To dv.Count - 1
        With dv(i)
            S = S & .Item("i") & vbTab & .Item("Dewey") & vbTab & .Item("Lvl") & vbTab & "'" & .Item("HID") & vbLf
        End With
    Next

    S = S & vbLf & vbLf

    dv.Sort = "HID"
    For i = 0 To dv.Count - 1
        With dv(i)
            S = S & .Item("i") & vbTab & .Item("Dewey") & vbTab & vbTab & .Item("Lvl") & vbTab & "'" & .Item("HID") & vbLf
        End With
    Next
    Dim t2 As Long = My.Computer.Clock.TickCount
    S = S & (Str(t2 - T1)) & " milliseconds"
    Clipboard.SetText(S)

    Dim P As String = ""
    Dim Tm As Long = My.Computer.Clock.TickCount
    For i = 0 To dv.Count - 1
        P = P & Str(i) & vbTab & dv(i).Item("i") & vbTab & ORDPATH.ToString(dv(i).Item("hid")) & vbTab & GetParent(dv(i).Item("dewey")) & vbTab & vbLf
        ' GetRoot(dv(i).Item("dewey"))
    Next
    MsgBox(P & vbLf & vbLf & My.Computer.Clock.TickCount - Tm & " msec")
End Sub
```

End Class